# print div with textarea incl. user input using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have this simple script that prints a part of a webpage.
However, it does not print user input.

My goal is to only print the form and the user input; not the rest of the webpage.

I do not want to use css; just js/jQuery and html.

My question is: how can I print various form input elements including the user input?

HTML:

```
<div id="print-content">
        <textarea>Print User Input</textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you're trying to do here? Also, there is not need for the form tags, so I'll edit them out and remove the tags.

Comment: @cmprogram: I am just trying to print a form with user input. Goal is to only print the form; not the rest of the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

The *current* value of an input is not represented in the HTML (only the *default* value), so it won't show up in `innerHTML`.

You would need to loop over all the inputs in the original page, read their `value` properties, then copy the values to the new inputs on the new page.

---

You'd probably be better off using CSS and `@media print` to hide the elements you don't want to be printed rather than rewriting the document with `innerHTML` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is I don't want to use css. Only js/jQuery and html

Comment: @ElsdenIep – Then follow the advice I gave in the second paragraph of the answer.

Comment: That is a bit too complicated for me. Do you have an example that I could alter for my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try by removing this  line `document.body.innerHTML = printContents;`

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  window.print();
}
```

```html
<div id="print-content">
  <form>
    <textarea>Print User Input</textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is: My script only prints content of id="print-content". Your script prints the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on chrome only.

```
 function printDiv(divName) {

    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).cloneNode(true);

    w = window.open();
    w.document.body.appendChild(printContents);
    w.print();
    w.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it is that simple: your script works great for me. Thanks!

Comment: Works great in Chrome, FF, Opera, Android. Not working in Edge and IE.

Comment: @Sven Liivak Your solutions worked for me but I also need to apply the styles of form on print. I tried appending styles in w.document.head but it didn't work. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @ajain Head is invisible element, you want to append styles to visible elements. e.g. w.document.body.style.background = "lightblue"

Comment: Would you please give me a proper definition of this code? Which function is doing the print operaion?